# How to deduce the "divide by a fraction" formula from the definition of division

Tags: algebra-precalculus, soft-question, arithmetic, binary-operations

From the comments I got, my question amonts to : can the " inverse of inverse" law be derived from the definition of division.

---

Division is defined as : $\dfrac AB =  A.\dfrac1B$, that is,

" dividisng by A by B is, by definition, mutiplicating A by the inverse of B".

My question is:

How do I derive from this definition, the equality:

$\frac{a}{b/c}$ = $\frac{ac}{b}$

I tried this:

$\frac{a}{b/c}$

= $\frac{a}{b\times1/c}$   ( applying the definition of division to the denominator)

=$\frac{a\times1}{b\times1/b}$  ( using " 1 is the identity for multiplication")

= $\frac ab$$\times$$\frac{1}{1/c}$   ( using $\frac{ab}{cd}$ = $\frac{a\times b}{c\times d}$ in the reverse sense)

But could not go further.

How to recover $\frac {c}{1}$  from  $\frac{1}{1/c}$ using exclusively the definition of division $\frac AB$ =  A.$\frac1B$ ?

It seems to me I am moving in a circle, since apparently I would need the formula I want to prove to obtain the last equality I want.

Comment: $$a(bc^{-1})^{-1}=a((c^{-1})^{-1}b^{-1})=a(cb^{-1})=(ac)b^{-1}$$where I have used the basic results$$(xy)^{-1}=y^{-1}x^{-1},\quad (x^{-1})^{-1}=x,\quad x(yz)=(xy)z$$in the group provided with multiplication.

Comment: There are a number of typos in your question. For instance, $\frac a{b/c}=\frac{ac}b$, rather than what you wrote. So I request that you go over your question and correct the errors.

Comment: @PeterForeman.Apparently, it is made use of " the inverse of the inverse of a is a " ( in exponential form) in the series of equalities you wrote.  This may be easy to prove in abstract algebra ( with exponents). But is there a way to show it in elementary algebra?

Comment: @Lubin. Thanks for pointing out the typos.

Comment: @PeterForeman. From what you say, I understand that the formula I want to prove requires  the law : " the inverse of the inverse of a is a itself"  ( or : 1 / (1/a) = a ) and , consequently, my formula cannot be proved using the definition of division alone.  Is it the case that the law of " inverse of inverse" can't be derived from the definition of division?

Comment: @RayLittleRock One does not need to define division but instead just use multiplication by the corresponding inverse elements as shown in my comment. In this case we just need an inverse element, $x^{-1}$, defined by $xx^{-1}=x^{-1}x=1$ to exist (which I assumed as you were considering division). Also, you do not need to use exponents to prove that $(x^{-1})^{-1}=x$. It follows from the definition of the inverse element.

Comment: $\frac 1{\frac 1c} *\frac 1c = 1$ by definition.  And $c*\frac 1c = 1$ by definition.  So if we *assume* the inverses are unique, we must conclude that $\frac 1{\frac 1c} = c$ because it can't equal anything else.... but... we can assume inverses are unique.  We must prove that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align}
   \dfrac{1}{\left\{\dfrac CD \right\}}
    &= \dfrac{1}{\left\{\dfrac CD \right\}} \cdot 1 \\
   &= \dfrac{1}{\left\{\dfrac CD \right\}} \cdot \dfrac DD \\
   &= \dfrac{1 \cdot D}{\dfrac CD\cdot D } \\
   &= \dfrac DC
\end{align}

Therefore

$$\dfrac AB \div \dfrac CD 
     = \dfrac AB \cdot \dfrac{1}{\left\{\dfrac CD \right\}}
     = \dfrac AB \cdot \dfrac DC 
     = \dfrac{AD}{BC}$$

Answer (score 0):

$1/(1/c)$

Here, according to the definition, we need to multiply 1 with the multiplicative inverse of (1/c)

Multiplicative inverse of a number is a number which when multiplied by the given number yields 1

So, here multiplicative inverse of (1/c) is c (you can check it by calculating),

Hence, $1/(1/c)$ = c

*I would not say the comments to the question are less informative or different from my answer but I presented this answer in my own way to make it clear.*

Comment: wish you " cheched" it by calculation :) will you? I mean, with proper justifications

Comment: I guess the subject of the comment by Ray LittleRock is not me

Comment: Or I should say I didn't get your comment

Answer (score 0):

Just do it:

$\frac a {\frac bc}$ will by definition be $a\cdot \frac 1{\frac bc}$

So we need to figure out what $\frac 1{\frac bc}$ is.

And it is the value $k$ so that $\frac bc\cdot k = 1$.[1]

So we need to solve for $(\frac bc)k  =(b\cdot \frac 1c)\cdot k = 1$.

We know that $(b\cdot \frac 1c)\cdot c = b\cdot(\frac 1c\cdot c)= b\cdot 1 = b$.

And so $(b\cdot \frac 1c)\cdot (c \cdot \frac 1b) = b\cdot (\frac 1c \cdot c)\cdot \frac 1b = b\cdot 1 \cdot \frac 1b = b\cdot \frac 1b = 1$.

So $\frac 1{\frac bc} = c\cdot \frac 1b = \frac cb$.

So $\frac a{\frac bc} = a\cdot \frac 1{\frac bc}=a\frac cb = a(c\cdot \frac 1b)=(ac)\frac 1b = \frac {ac}b$

......

[1]

This assumes that for any $m \ne 0$ that there exists a $k$ that $mk =1$ *and* that $k$ is unique.

That such a $k$ exists is the definition of $\mathbb Q$ is a field.

We can prove $k$ is unique.

If $k$ and $j$ are both inverses of $m$ then  $mk =1=km $ and $mj = 1=jm$.

That means that $kmj =(km)j=1\cdot j = j$ but $kmj=k(mj) =k\cdot 1 =k$.  SO $j = k$.

And inverses are unique.

We can use that to prove that $\frac 1{\frac 1c} = c$.

because $c \times \frac 1c = 1$ that means.... *by definition* that $c$ is the inverse of $\frac 1c$.  SO $c = \frac 1{\frac 1c}$.